# Fetch a key value from the JMS request header in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Have the following as the request header in my JSM request,

```
study_ID    MSGtest
Initial Context Factory com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
client_ID   MSGtest
TransactionID   39594bf1-0410-476c-9cb6-0ce3102ce182
JMSCorrelationId null
JMSMessageId     ID:ber_967v_apps.2BD45F5F053B29487C3:8
JMSTimestamp     1632223197081
JMSType          null
JMSExpiration    0
JMSPriority      4
```

Want to fetch the `TransactionID` from the request header, how to do this in JMeter ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had similar requirement in past, this is how we resolve it. Please add a JSR223 preprocessor to generate your transaction id and fetch it from anywhere,

```
def transactionID = '${__UUID}'
vars.put('TRANS_UID',String.valueOf(transactionID))
```

And in the variable value where you want to pass it use,

```
${__groovy(vars.get('TRANS_UID'),)}
```

You can use this `TRANS_UID` anywhere, JMS request header is bit tricky.

Comment: Thank you Jyoti Prakash